# iPhone - Removing a presented view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

On a view controller I have a button that will present another view controller. From the second view controller, I can go to other view controllers, but not necessarily back to the one that got me here. If this is the case, how can I remove the original view controller?

Comment: Can you post code as to what you have tried so far. Also what are you using to load the view controller. Is it UINavigationController? Have you tried popping the view controller?

Comment: looks like sheepy question for me...please paste some code u have tried so far...

Comment: If I use dismissViewController or popViewController, won't either of these take me to the original view controller? I am looking for a way, if possible, to dismiss the initial view controller.

Comment: So you want to remove the root view controller is that correct?

Comment: Yes! That's what I want to do.

Comment: The flow of the application that I would like to do had me going for a solution like this, so I would like to change the root view controller depending on where I am going.

Comment: The following tutorial shows you how to change the root view controller [Changing the Root View Controller](http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/changing-a-uinavigationcontroller%E2%80%99s-root-view-controller/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your description is a bit unclear here. There could be 3 different cases here:

1. Moving through navigation controller hierarchy
2. Breaking out of navigation controller hierarchy to another view controller
3. Just adding another view controller to current in navigation controller stack

In first case you can use methods of UINavigationController:

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

and use viewControllers property to navigate through the stack.

Ina second one, if you want to break out the hierarchy to one completely another view controller, then simply do it by:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController = newController;
```

or even better: add second line in completion block of first line.

Or in third case, if you want only to make one exception, but otherwise stay in navigation controller stack, then use methods:

```
- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController
- (void)removeFromParentViewController
```

Answer (score 20):

That depends on how you actually presented the current view controller. 
If it was modally, then

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

If it was pushed using a navigation controller:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```